# Anathem and Bread-Making

Tags: neal-stephenson, anathem

Mild spoilers for Neal Stephenson's *Anathem*:

> When Erasmas is quarantined on first arriving at the Convox, he says "They’d provided me with everything I needed to make bread". But how is this possible? Dried yeast is an industrial product that's surely not available in a concent, and even if it was available at the Convox (there *were* Saecular foodstuffs in his trailer), Erasmas wouldn't know how to use it. The avout would bake their bread the mediaeval way, using some of yesterday's dough as a starter for today's bread. You can't just leave it lying around in a trailer module in the same way as you can with flour and salt.

Comment: You don't need yeast to make flatbread.

Comment: Yeast powder often comes in sachets with instructions

Comment: @Richard Saecular yeast powder would have its instructions in Kinagrams, which Erasmas couldn't read.

Comment: I haven't read the book recently, but if he had a few days he could start a new sourdough culture using whatever wild yeast wafted in through the window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Neil Stephenson's *Anathem,* Part 9, Imbrase:

> Half the kitchen was oc­cu­pied by bot­tled water, pal­letized and
>   stacked. The cup­boards had been stocked with an odd mix­ture of
>   ex­tra­muros gro­ceries and **fresh pro­duce** from the tan­gles and
>   ar­bore­tums of Tre­de­garh.

It's not specifically addressed, but if there was fresh produce, there's no reason there couldn't be some starter dough.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seem like he spends enough time to make a yeast bread....They tend to have a long proofing/rising cycle.

That being said, there is no reason that they would be restricted to "mediaeval" bread making: remember, despite their monastic lives, they're anything but uneducated, and the process of making "dried yeast" is actually quite simple. Generally you just use a potato or grain mash as as growth media, and when it's all nicely yeasted out, you spread it flat and dry it. Crumble it up, and voila, dry yeast.